# Using Curl and Grad in cylindrical coordinates gives different result than in Cartesian

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector, vector-calculus, algebra

I am doing a quite elementary calculation to verify

$$
    \vec \nabla\cdot V = \vec\nabla \times \vec A
$$

Where $V$ is just some scalar function in $\rho$, $\phi$ and $z$ and $A$ is defined as

$$
    A = A_\rho \hat e_\rho + A_\phi \hat e_\phi + A_z \hat e_z
$$

If I now use the Mathematica functions `Curl` and `Grad` to calculate

```
curlA = Curl[Coefficient[A, {eρ, eϕ, ez}], {ρ, ϕ, z}, "Cylindrical"]
gradV = Grad[V, {ρ, ϕ, z}, "Cylindrical"]
Simplify[curlA - gradV]
```

I find that this is not zero.

However, if I first convert $V$ and $A$ to cartesian coordinates using the coordinate transformation

$$
    \rho \to \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
    \phi \to \arctan{\frac{x}{y}}\\
    \hat e_\rho \to \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\hat e_x + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\hat   e_y\\
    \hat e_\phi \to -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\hat e_x + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\hat e_y
$$

And then use:

```
curlAcart = Curl[Coefficient[Acart, {ex, ey, ez}], {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"]
gradVcart = Grad[Vcart, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"]
Simplify[curlAcart - gradVcart]
```

This does return zero.

If anyone wants to know the exact forms of $A$ and $V$ they are as follows:

```
A = q ((z - a)/rp - (z + a)/rm) eϕ
V = q (1/rp - 1/rm)
```

where:

```
rp = Sqrt[ρ^2 + (z - a)^2];
rm = Sqrt[ρ^2 + (z + a)^2];
```

If anyone has any idea why this is not working out I would be very grateful.

Comment: Usually $\phi$ is $\arctan(y/x)$ or even `ArcTan[x,y]`.

Comment: It seems I copied this wrong to my question. In my code I indeed use `ArcTan[x,y]`. I just tried to change this in my question but I get an error saying I formatted my code incorrectly (even when just clicking edit and trying to save it immediately). If anyone can update my question to use arctan(y/x) instead of arctan(x/y) that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

If I use the built-in function `TransformedField` to convert between coordinate systems, I get a non-zero result in Cartesian coordinates, and that result is the same one as found in cylindrical coordinates after accounting for the coordinate transformation:

```
diff=Simplify[curlA-gradV];
avec=Coefficient[A,{eρ,eϕ,ez}];
avecCart=TransformedField["Cylindrical"->"Cartesian",avec,{ρ,ϕ,z}->{x,y,zc}]/.zc->z//FullSimplify;
curlACart=Curl[avecCart,{x,y,z}]//FullSimplify;
VCart=TransformedField["Cylindrical"->"Cartesian",V,{ρ,ϕ,z}->{x,y,zc}]/.zc->z//FullSimplify;
gradVCart=Grad[VCart,{x,y,z}];
diffCart=FullSimplify[curlACart-gradVCart];
diffCart-TransformedField["Cylindrical"->"Cartesian",diff,{ρ,ϕ,z}->{x,y,zc}]/.zc->z//FullSimplify
(*{0,0,0}*)
```

[Note that since `TransformedField` doesn't allow the same coordinate name to be used in both the source and target systems, I use `zc` for the Cartesian $z$ which is then replaced with `z` after the conversion.]

I therefore suspect that you made some error converting between cylindrical and Cartesian coordinates.  Without seeing that code, however, it is impossible to comment on what the error was.